# ggplot change bar colors and legend titles in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm mapping three different plots onto one plot. Getting the legend titles to be correct took some time but now I can't seem to change the colors of the bar plots without messing up the titles.
I would like the bar colors to be simpler (greyscale or black/red) and I'd like to change the legend titles. I can usually change one thing I want but I end up losing other features that are helpful
Thanks!

```
ggplot(data = media_impact_by_state) +
  #plot the deviation from state mean for believe CC is
  geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(GeoName,happening - mean(happening)),
               y = happening - mean(happening),
               fill = "Believe in Climate Change"),
               stat = 'identity') +
  scale_color_manual(values = "black",label = "Boo") +
  #plot the deviation from the mean for distrust of climate scientists
  geom_bar(aes(x= GeoName,
               y= trustclimsciSSTOppose - mean(trustclimsciSSTOppose),
               fill = "Do Not Trust Climate Scientists"),
           stat = 'identity') +
  #plot the difference in belief and and trust
  geom_point(aes(x = GeoName,
                 y = (happening - mean(happening))- 
                    (trustclimsciSSTOppose - mean(trustclimsciSSTOppose)),
                    color = "(Belief) - (Distrust)")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "black") +
  labs(x = "State",
       y = "% Deviation from Mean") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hard to be very helpful w/o seeing how your data is organized. Typically aes(fill = column_name_from_data); scale_*_manual(name = "legend title", values = c("red", "black") will get you closer; should only have one scale_color_manual function; HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you provided no data I could not check my code but this should do what you are looking for:

1. In my opinion it's not a good idea to set the labels inside the geom. Simply use easy placeholders like "fill1" or ...
2. To assign the right colors and labels make use of named vectors inside `scale_fill_manual`.

```
    ggplot(data = media_impact_by_state) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(GeoName,happening - mean(happening)),
                   y = happening - mean(happening), fill = "fill1"),
               stat = 'identity') +
      scale_color_manual(values = "black", label = "Boo") +
      geom_bar(aes(x= GeoName, y= trustclimsciSSTOppose - mean(trustclimsciSSTOppose), fill = "fill2"),
               stat = 'identity') +
      geom_point(aes(x = GeoName, y = (happening - mean(happening)) - 
                       (trustclimsciSSTOppose - mean(trustclimsciSSTOppose)),
                     color = "(Belief) - (Distrust)")) +
      scale_color_manual(values = "black") +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c(fill1 = "red", fill2 = "black"),
                        labels = c(fill1 = "Believe in Climate Change", fill2 = "Do Not Trust Climate Scientists")) +
      labs(x = "State",
           y = "% Deviation from Mean") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```